# can't test eloquent with php unit

Tags: testing, eloquent, phpunit

I try to implement some unit tests with phpUnit, on a project that uses Eloquent. The installation is made with composer for both frameworks. But when I try to implement a simple example test, it fails loading database.php

the example test

```
include("database.php");
class ArticleControllerTest extends TestCase
{


    public function testAccueil()
    {
        //récupère la date du jour
        $a = \app\model\Article::first();

        $this->assertInternalType("string", $a->titreGeneral);

    }
}
```

Database.php

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Illuminate\Container\Container;
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;
use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;

$capsule = new Capsule;

$capsule->addConnection(array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'spectacles',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => 'root',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => ''
));
$capsule->setEventDispatcher(new Dispatcher(new Container));
$capsule->setAsGlobal();

$capsule->bootEloquent();
```

error message with these script (the database is in the right folder)

```
PHP Warning:  include(../../database.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/spectacles/TestUnits/controllerTest/ArticleControllerTest.php on line 6

Warning: include(../../database.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/spectacles/TestUnits/controllerTest/ArticleControllerTest.php on line 6

PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '../../database.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/spectacles/TestUnits/controllerTest/ArticleControllerTest.php on line 6

Warning: include(): Failed opening '../../database.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/spectacles/TestUnits/controllerTest/ArticleControllerTest.php on line 6
```

And error messages when I try to put the code in database.php directly in the example test :

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

I don't think the problem comes prom the paths (they are the right paths). Did I miss something ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory` means the database could not connect.

The other errors are clearly telling you that the script could not include the `database.php` file.

The paths are not correct. You are not properly understanding how `include()` works. Read http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php.

In a nutshell, the following code expects the `database.php` file to exist in the same directory as the file itself, or on the include path.

```
include("database.php");
class ArticleControllerTest extends TestCase
{
...
```

These may also help:

- [Understanding include_path output PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39354024/include-config-and-database-from-other-files)
- [Include Config and Database from other files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39354648/934739)

Comment: There is more details on this problem and on how to avoid it here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Actually I gifured out the problem. I didn"t understand why the include wasn't working, cause database.php was in the same directory. Fanally I don't know why but PHPUnit searches the element included from the root of the project folder. 

And I solved the other problem adding this line 
    'unix_socket'   => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'
in the database.php