# Include Config and Database from other files

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, I have a situation where I have several files in different directories and need to figure out how to link them all together. Here is the structure:

- /home/username/public_html/index.php
- /home/username/public_html/secure/index.php
- /home/username/public_html/elements/includes/db.php
- /home/username/config.ini

Ok, so in both of my index.php files i have this include referencing db.php:

**index.php**

```
<?php include("elements/includes/db.php"); ?>
```

and **secure/index.php**

```
<?php include("../elements/includes/db.php"); ?>
```

Now inside of the db.php file, I have the following reference to config.ini:

```
$config = parse_ini_file('../../../config.ini');
```

I know its not picking up because it should be relative to index.php instead of db.php, but how would I reference these files correctly? I want my config.ini to be outside of the public_html directory.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use magic constants e.g. `__DIR__`, see [Predefinied Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php).

```
.
├── config.ini
└── public_html
    ├── elements
    │   └── includes
    │       └── db.php
    ├── index.php
    └── secure
        └── index.php
```

**public_html/elements/includes/db.php**

```
<?php

$config = parse_ini_file(
    __DIR__  . '/../../../config.ini'
);
```

**public_html/index.php**

```
<?php

include __DIR__ . '/elements/includes/db.php';
```

**public_html/secure/index.php**

```
<?php

include __DIR__ . '/../elements/includes/db.php';
```

Note: I recommend using `require` instead of `include`, see [require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php).

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` so that you don't need to figure out relative paths on each file:

```
 $config = parse_ini_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../config.ini');
```

Comment: ahhh, i didnt know you could go backward from a document root call... i thought that was the final location when used... thank you!!! I'll give it a try.

Comment: Warning: parse_ini_file(/home/username/public_html./../config.ini): failed to open stream     <--- could not get it to reference a directory back... tried a few variations: ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'../config.ini')

Comment: Odd that it's throwing in the extra period after `public_html`

Comment: Also, make sure the config file is readable by the web server user (possibly apache)